# error C2027: use of undefined type 'edge'

Tags: c++, class, types, undefined

I have this error occuring when trying to compile. I searched for help, but all answers focused on including separated files. But this is only one .cpp file, so it didnt help. I mentioned "class edge;" at the beginning of the code. I have included iostream, string, map and set.

Here is the code:

...

```
using namespace std;

class edge;

class vertex{
public:
    string name;
    set<edge*> edges;
    int distance;

    vertex(string name){
        this->name = name;
    }

    void print_neighbours(){
        cout << "vertex:" << name << "    neighbours: ";
        for(set<edge*>::iterator it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); it++){
            cout << (*it)->getVertex(this->name)->name << " "; //compile error here
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   
};

class edge{
public:
    vertex* from;
    vertex* to; 
    int length;

    edge(vertex* ver1, vertex* ver2, int length=1){
        this->from = ver1;
        this->to = ver2;
        this->length = length;
    }

    vertex* getVertex(string v1){
        if(v1 == this->from->name){
            return this->to;
        }
        else if(v1 == this->to->name){
            return this->from;
        }
    }

};
```

...

Sorry for the formating, its my first day around.

Comment: You are using the `edge` type in the definition of your `vertex` functions, before the `edge` type is defined.  Declaration is not enough in that case.  Your case should work if you move the `edge` definition before `vertex`, and forward declare `vertex` instead.

Comment: put class declarations in the head files, and implementation of member function into the Cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling an `edge` method here:

```
(*it)->getVertex(this->name)->name
```

so you need the full `edge` class definition. A forward declaration doesn't suffice.

You can fix this by moving the `edge` code that needs the full `vertex` definition out of the `edge` definition and into an implementation file, and vice versa.

Comment: thank you for the comment. but as you can see, i on the other hand use vertex in class edge. so it produces the same error but with type 'vertex'.

Comment: @user3631453 Yes, you will have to fix that. There are plenty of questions on that. Basically, move the code that needs the full class definitions to implementation files.

Comment: i have never had to do that, thats why I didnt know. thank you, will try to fix it.